# Signing all xml-files in directory using batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I'm trying to write a windows batch script to

1. Search for the first `.pem` certificate in directory
2. Ask the user for its password
3. Sign all `.xml`-files in the directory with this certificate using openSSL

The name of the signature should be the same name as the `.xml`-file but with an `.sig` suffix, e.g. `XML: this.xml <=> signature: this.xml.sig`

The openSSL-command to sign files is

> openssl dgst -binary -sha512 -sign  -out

So to create the signature "this.xml.sig" of the xml-file "this.xml" by using the cert "cert.pem" I have to use the following command

> openssl dgst -binary -sha512 -sign cert.pem -out this.xml.sig this.xml

Then you are promted to enter the password of the cert which should be used to sign the XML.

So I wrote the following script but when I double-click the `.bat`-script I have the following problems:

- The black command box is opened and closed immendetly but nothing happens. It seems that the script doesn't find the find the `.pem`-file in directory - but there is one.
- When I change the first `for` loop to use recursive search (add `/r` before `.`) it finds a `.pem`-file in a subdirectory and ask me to enter a password but after this the command window is closed and no signature is created

The script:

```
@echo off
Rem placeholder for cert-file
set cert=""

for %%g in (*.pem) do (
  echo "Certificate found: " %%g
  set cert=%%g
  Rem exit loop as we found a cert-file
  goto :SignFiles
)

echo "No cert file found"
exit

:SignFiles
Rem Ask user for Cert-Password
set /p password="Please input cert-password: " 

Rem debug
echo %password%

Rem sign all xml-files in directory
for %%g in (*.xml) do (
  echo "Sign XML-File: " %%g
  Rem sign file and pass saved password for signing
  openssl dgst -binary -sha512 -out %%g.sig -sign=%cert% %%g < %password%
)

pause
exit
```

Can anyone help me to get the script working as intended?

**edit**
Updated script chaning the comments form `::` to `Rem`. Behavior remains the same. The black command box opens and closes immideatly without asking for password and/or creating signatures

**edit2**
Removed the `.` in the foor loops. Now the loops are running but not fully working. When trying to execute the openssl command I get `System can not find the file`. To debug this I added

```
echo %cert% > cert.txt
echo %%g > file.txt
```

to the second foor loop and saw that the names of certificate and xml-file are correctly written to cert.txt/file.txt. But still no signature is created.

Comment: Change all commentary/remarks from **`::`** to **`Rem`**.

Comment: @Compo This doesn't change the behavior :(

Comment: Your script cannot work with remarks inside loops using **`::`**, just change them to **`Rem`**, rerun your script and update your question with the updated code.

Comment: @Compo Updated question with changed comments but still no change of the scripts behavior

Comment: You've used **`for . %%g in (`** twice, change them both to **`for %%g in (`**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for . %%g ...
```

should be

```
for %%g ...
```

Your code would yield a syntax error, which would result in the window closing if you ran the batch by simply clicking it. To see the syntax error, you need to run your batch from the prompt.

You won't see the messages that you are deliberately producing if you run the batch by clicking it, as the command following the `echo` is an `exit`. Possibly insert a `pause` command before the exit to be sure of seeing the message - or redirect the message to a file...

Comment: This helped me to get the script at least running, but still not fully working. Please have a look at the updated question

Comment: You need to `echo %password%| openssl...`, that is the redirector should be pipe. Using `<` expects a file named `%password%` which probably doesn't exist, so the error messsage you report is generated.

Comment: After I changed the openssl command to correctly pass the password via `-passin` parameter it works. Thanks for helping me by showing my syntax errors!